# How to make Maven unit test code coverage work

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, jacoco

In Eclipse, I have used EcLEmma to see the unit test code coverage. Which worked fine.
Therefore I have tried to use the JaCoCo plugin for Maven to see the same report with Surefire from Maven build, or even better, with a certain profile, or in the site cycle. Without success. All suggested solutions here didn't work for me.

What is the best way to get a unit test code coverage report (with surefire)?

[Edit]
to be more specific why jacoco failed for me.... as I got always the
Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data

from the pom
in the properties

```
    <jacoco.it.execution.data.file>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</jacoco.it.execution.data.file>
    <jacoco.ut.execution.data.file>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</jacoco.ut.execution.data.file>
```

in the Build section

```
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>${jacoco.version}</versionRange>
                                    <executions>
                                        <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent 
                                            which is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
                                        <execution>
                                            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                                            <goals>
                                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <configuration>
                                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution 
                                                    data. -->
                                                <destFile>${jacoco.ut.execution.data.file}</destFile>
                                                <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for 
                                                    JaCoCo runtime agent. -->
                                                <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                                            </configuration>
                                        </execution>
                                        <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created 
                                            after unit tests have been run. -->
                                        <execution>
                                            <id>post-unit-test</id>
                                            <phase>test</phase>
                                            <goals>
                                                <goal>report</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <configuration>
                                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution 
                                                    data. -->
                                                <dataFile>${jacoco.ut.execution.data.file}</dataFile>
                                                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                                                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                                            </configuration>
                                        </execution>
                                        <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent 
                                            which is passed as VM argument when Maven the Failsafe plugin is executed. -->
                                        <execution>
                                            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                            <goals>
                                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <configuration>
                                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution 
                                                    data. -->
                                                <destFile>${jacoco.it.execution.data.file}</destFile>
                                                <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for 
                                                    JaCoCo runtime agent. -->
                                                <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                                            </configuration>
                                        </execution>
                                        <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests 
                                            after integration tests have been run. -->
                                        <execution>
                                            <id>post-integration-test</id>
                                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                            <goals>
                                                <goal>report</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                            <configuration>
                                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution 
                                                    data. -->
                                                <dataFile>${jacoco.it.execution.data.file}</dataFile>
                                                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                                                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                                            </configuration>
                                        </execution>
                                    </executions>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

was my last try but the pom becomes bigger and bigger without any result

which failes with

configuring report plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jxr-plugin:2.3

configuring report plugin org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946

Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:......\target\jacoco.exec

Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:......\target\jacoco-it.exec

.... => long project path

Comment: You use the `jacoco-maven-plugin` ? Explain what you did and tried please, then we might be ale to help.

Comment: added the pom fragments for jacoco to the question

Comment: Add the error message that you are getting when running your build. I wild guess by what you have said is the path of your execution data file. Other than that we can't help any further without the error message of your build.

Comment: sorry, added also that

Comment: Why did you put this in the eclipse lifecycle-mapping plugin? Are you running maven inside eclipse or from the command line?

Comment: this was just one of many tries to make it run....I try to run it either on console and in eclipse

Answer (score 50):

Thanks user3732793

Personnaly, I only needed to add this to my `pom.xml`

```
<project>
...

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <!-- Code Coverage report generation -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-code-coverage-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then I am running

```
mvn test
```

and I get the HTML report under `./target/site/jacoco/*.html`

Comment: With this cfg, SonarQube scanner finds the xml report without any other setting.  The latest plugin version can be found at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin

Answer (score 11):

As always the solution is easy after reading the documentation which provides example poms [jacoco documentation](http://eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html).

This profile:

```
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <env>test</env>
            <gebEnv>test</gebEnv>
            <jacoco.skip>false</jacoco.skip>
            <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
            <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

This in the `build` section:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And this in the `reporting` section:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        </plugin>
```

Than this does all:

```
mvn clean install site -P test
```